# uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' ->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I was trying out a sample thread program from google and i am getting a runtime exception.

Is there any website that gives an example of how to use runloops along with threads.
I need to set two events and spawn a thread and to do another function parallely.

```
// Runner.m

#import "Runner.h"

@implementation Runner

    - (void)rumMe:(id)ignored {

        NSLog(@"Running with threads!!");
    }

@end

// Runner.h

@interface Runner : NSObject

    -(void)rumMe:(id)ignored;

@end

// Thread1.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Runner.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Runner* runner = [Runner new]; 
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(runMe:) toTarget:runner withObject:nil];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Runtime Exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** 
-[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** 
-[Runner runMe:])'
```

Comment: Okay, having read a little, you probably can use new, so that isn't the problem

Comment: This is a typo. Look at your method declaration: `ru` m `Me:` and your argument to `detachNewThreadSelector:`. `ru` n `Me`

Comment: @Josh:The argument i'm passing to detachNewThreadSelector is (runMe:) and not as (runMe)

Comment: I'm not talking about the colon; that part is correct. You've got an `m` in your declaration and an `n` in your call.

Comment: @Josh:correctly pointed out.Thanks.Its now running without any exception.But its not printing me the strings "Running with threads" when the thread calls the selector-runMe method.why is it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part: you had a typo

```
// method declaration
rumMe:   with an _m_
// call
runMe:   with an _n_
```

Second part: your main function is returning and causing the program to exit before you have given the thread a chance to do anything. In this simple simple example, you could simply

```
sleep(2);
```

right after the call to `detachNewThreadSelector:`

In more complex cases, you might need to make a call to `CFRunLoopRun();` on the main thread, or take other action to keep the second thread alive.

Comment: Casewell:Thanks for making me understand about threading. will move forward with some complex program in Threading.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a typo. The method in `Runner` is defined as `rumMe`, but in the main program you use `runMe`.